# Trying to use swaggerGroup but I can't get it working properly

Tags: swagger-ui

So I've been messing around with swagger and swagger-ui and would like to be able to separate my api by different groups. This is my SwaggerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig){
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customBankImplementation(){
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
            .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Simple Business Demo API",
                "API for a simple business structure FOR BANKS",
                "API's terms of service", 
                "someone@someplace.com", 
                "API Licence Type", 
                "API License URL"))
                .swaggerGroup("bankGroup")
                .includePatterns(".*/bank.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customMerchantImplementation(){
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
            .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Simple Business Demo API",
                "API for a simple business structure For MERCHATNTS",
                "API's terms of service", 
                "someone@someplace.com", 
                "API Licence Type", 
                "API License URL"))
                .swaggerGroup("merchantGroup")
                .includePatterns(".*/merchant.*");
    }

}
```

When I type in http://localhost:8080/apidocs/index.html

http://localhost:8080/apidocs/index.html?group=bankGroup or

http://localhost:8080/apidocs/index.html?group=merchantGroup it brings me to the bank api.

I can't figure out how to get it to show my merchant api, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am also wondering should I only have one index.html or should I have separate ones for each controller class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on further examination and testing I think I was mistaken about the functionality of the "swaggerGroup", I'm pretty sure it only allows you to show a JSON representation of your api and doesn't actually affect the swagger ui stuff at all.